# Free SW for mapping the Network

Tags: gratis, networking

Are there tools that map/scan the LAN and gather (as much as possible) information about the HW and/or network topology? Ideally, it would be great if that tool could also "draw" a topology of the LAN.
I already checked there a very cool tools that can do that, but lets asume I'm in a small company with a small team and there's no money for such tools. Thank you.

Comment: How about a mobile app?  Does your router not have these facilities? Might be cheaper to change the router.

Comment: Perhaps try command line tool `ntop` or `ntopng`. Here is an article about the idea ["Rethinking Flow Visualisation in ntopng"](https://www.ntop.org/ntopng/rethinking-flow-visualisation-in-ntopng/)

Comment: Well at home yeah, my router has an overview of the connected devices. But here in the workplace I don't have that option. Lets assume the only option I have scanning the network/devices from my own machine.